# Does spring-boot-admin support sso?

Tags: single-sign-on, spring-boot-admin

I'm trying to integrate spring-boot-admin with my corporate SSO, does spring-boot-admin support sso login? I cannot find documentation about it.

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work. Steps to implement:

1. Create controller with an endpoint that the sso provider will call.
2. In the endpoint, put the logic for sso integration,
3. On success, redirect to /applications
4. On failure, throw an exception

```
@Controller
public class SsoIntegration {

    // this does addition authentication stuff, like sets up the 
    // right authorities...etc
    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider;


    // my sso provider creates a vanity url that redirects to 
    // this endpoint and passes 2 request params using POST
    @RequestMapping(value={"/sso"}, method = {RequestMethod.POST})
    public String ssologin (
              @RequestParam(name="param1") String param1, 
              @RequestParam(name="param2") String param2 ) 
    {

        // do your sso integration logic here
        // eg...
        SsoUtil util = new SsoUtil();
        String userInfo = util.decrypt(param1, param2, ...);

        ...
        if (authenticationProvider.authenticate( userInfo )) {
          Authentication postAuthentication = ...// populate your successfully authenticated user
           

          // these next lines are the important stuff
          // 1. set the postAuthentication into the security context 
          SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(postAuthentication); 

          // 2. redirect to the applications page
          return "redirect:/applications";
        }
        
        // authentication failed, throw an exception...
        throw new RuntimeException ("Sso Authentication failed");
    }
}
```